# Unable to change certain array data by passing address of pointer to an array as argument to the function

Tags: c, pointers, printf, c-strings, conversion-specifier

The b array stores the address of the a array which contains single character value. But by calling the fun function I want the the each **b** array element may contain string (multicharacter) value.

Suppose I want to change the ***b[1]** value in the array by passing address of array pointer as argument to the **fun** function. But I am getting the segmentation fault after compilation .How to resolve it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void fun(char **x)
{
    strcpy(*x,"aaa");
}

int main(void)
{
    int itr;
    char a[5]={'a','b','c','d','e'};
    char *b[5] ={&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3],&a[4]};
    char *c[5]={"ab","cd","ef","gh","ij"};

    for(itr=0;itr<5;itr++)
    {
        printf("%c\t",a[itr]);
        printf("%c\t",*b[itr]);
        printf("%s\n",c[itr]);
    }
    fun(&b[1]);

    printf("%s\n",*b[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems you mean printf("%s\n",b[1]); instead of printf("%s\n",*b[1])

Comment: `*b[1]` is the same as `b[1][0]`, which is the first ***character*** in the "string" pointed to by `b[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

In this call

```
printf("%s\n",*b[1]);
```

the expression `*b[1]` has the type `char` while the conversion specifier `s` expects an argument of the type `char *`

So either you should write

```
printf( "%c\n", *b[1] );
```

or

```
printf( "%s\n", b[1] );
```